# VBA - merge set number of rows in first column

Tags: vba, merge

I have seen some VBA examples on here allowing one to merge set numbers of cells, but none exactly as I need it.

What I would like to do is go down the entire column A:A and merge every four rows, **starting** with cell A4. I know this involves changing the reference cell but I'm not skilled enough with the language to know how to do this without screwing up the cycle.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34d57falmbb4n2p/Book4.xlsx?dl=0) is an example of the data I would like to format. Thanks in advance for any and all help with this.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set Count to the number of merged cells that you want and run the MergeColA.

```
Sub MergeColA()
Dim Count As Integer
Count = 10
MergeCells (Count)
End Sub
Sub MergeCells(Count As Integer)
For i = 4 To 4 * count Step (4)
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 3)
r.Merge
Next i
End Sub
```